# Python method chaining in functional programming style

Tags: python, functional-programming, python-itertools, functools, toolz

Below is Python code, where the `process_request_non_fp` method shows how to handle the problem with IF-ELSE condition (make-api -> load-db -> notify).

I'm trying to get rid of IF-ELSE and chain in functional way with ERROR being handled in special method.

Is there any helper from functools, toolz etc to achieve this in simple functional way?

```
import random
from pydantic import BaseModel


class APP_ERROR(BaseModel):
    error_message: str


class DB_ERROR(APP_ERROR):
    pass


class API_ERROR(APP_ERROR):
    pass


class NOTIFICATION_ERROR(APP_ERROR):
    pass


class Request(BaseModel):
    req_id: str


class Response(BaseModel):
    response: str


class Ack(BaseModel):
    email: str


def get_api_data(request: Request) -> Response | API_ERROR:
    if random.choice([True, False]):
        print(" Success !! API data successfully retrieved")
        return Response(response="Success")
    else:
        print(" Fail !! API data FAILED")
        return API_ERROR(error_message="API Error")


def load_db(response: Response) -> Ack | DB_ERROR:
    if random.choice([True, False]):
        print(" Success !!  Data loaded to DB")
        return Ack(email="test@gmail.com")
    else:
        print("Fail !! DB Error")
        return DB_ERROR(error_message="DB Error")


def notify(ack: Ack) -> bool | NOTIFICATION_ERROR:
    if random.choice([True, False]):
        print(" Success !! Email notification sent")
        return True
    else:
        print("Fail !! Email notification sent")
        return NOTIFICATION_ERROR(error_message="Notification error")


def process_request_non_fp(req: Request) -> bool:
    resp = get_api_data(request=req)
    if type(resp) is Response:
        api_res = load_db(response=resp)
        if type(api_res) is Ack:
            ack_resp = notify(api_res)
            if type(ack_resp) is bool:
                return ack_resp
            else:
                return False
        else:
            return False
    else:
        return False


def process_request_fp(req: Request) -> bool:
    # (get_api_data)(load_db)(notify)(req).else(lambda x -> API_ERROR : print(Error))
    # How to implement this in functional way
    pass


process_request_non_fp(Request(req_id="MY_REQUEST"))
```

Comment: Could you explain more what you mean by "with ERROR being handled in special method"?  As for the if-else, I would change it to just use 3 guard clauses, and then the `else:` and nesting aren't needed.

Comment: I want to avoid IF-ELSE, use Option, Either these kind of FP constructs for clean function chaining.

Comment: Method chaining isn't really "functional"; it's the special case of composition of endofunctions where the functions are called for their side effects.

Comment: You could use exceptions instead. And that's not method chaining. For chaining, one would return an object that has the next method(s) you want. Method chaining would be something like `get_api_data(request=req).load_db().notify()` where the interim objects had the state needed for the next call.

Comment: If you want to indicate to future readers which solution you preferred, mark the answer as accepted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The desired behavior can be obtained using Either-Monad and currying

```
import random
from pydantic import BaseModel
from pymonad.tools import curry
from pymonad.either import Either, Left, Right


class APP_ERROR(BaseModel):
    error_message: str


class DB_ERROR(APP_ERROR):
    pass


class API_ERROR(APP_ERROR):
    pass


class NOTIFICATION_ERROR(APP_ERROR):
    pass


class Request(BaseModel):
    req_id: str


class Response(BaseModel):
    response: str


class Ack(BaseModel):
    email: str


@curry(1)
def get_api_data(request: Request) -> Response | API_ERROR:
    if random.choice([True, False]):
        print(f" Success !! {request} API data successfully retrieved")
        return Response(response="Success")
    else:
        print(" Fail !! API data FAILED")
        return Left(API_ERROR(error_message="API Error"))


@curry(1)
def load_db(response: Response) -> Ack | DB_ERROR:
    if random.choice([True, False]):
        print(f" Success !!  {response} Data loaded to DB")
        return Ack(email="test@gmail.com")
    else:
        print("Fail !! DB Error")
        return Left(DB_ERROR(error_message="DB Error"))


@curry(1)
def notify(ack: Ack) -> bool | NOTIFICATION_ERROR:
    if random.choice([True, False]):
        print(f" Success !! {ack} Email notification sent")
        return True
    else:
        print("Fail !! Email notification sent")
        return Left(NOTIFICATION_ERROR(error_message="Notification error"))


def process_request_non_fp(req: Request) -> bool:
    resp = get_api_data(request=req)
    if type(resp) is Response:
        api_res = load_db(response=resp)
        if type(api_res) is Ack:
            ack_resp = notify(api_res)
            if type(ack_resp) is bool:
                return ack_resp
            else:
                return False
        else:
            return False
    else:
        return False


def process_request_fp(req: Request) -> bool:
    result = (
        Either.insert(req)
        .then(get_api_data)
        .then(load_db)
        .then(notify)
        .either(
            lambda on_failure: print(f"Error: {on_failure}"),
            lambda on_success: on_success,
        )
    )
    print(result)


process_request_fp(Request(req_id="MY_REQUEST"))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid `if-else` using assignment expression.

```
if type(resp = get_api_data(request=req)) is Response and type(api_res := load_db(response=resp)) is ACK and type(ack_resp := notify(api_res)) is bool:
    return ack_resp
return false
```

Also you can just avoid redundant `else` after `return` in your code.

```
def process_request_non_fp(req: Request) -> bool:
    resp = get_api_data(request=req)
    if type(resp) is Response:
        api_res = load_db(response=resp)
        if type(api_res) is Ack:
            ack_resp = notify(api_res)
            if type(ack_resp) is bool:
                return ack_resp
     return False
```